# Vim variable length wildcard search and replace?

Tags: vim, wildcard, replace, substitution

I'm trying to clean a Frontpage-generated html file, and there are a ton of tag attributes I need to delete, like:

```
style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: Trebuchet MS; color: blue"
style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; text-underline: single"
style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; text-underline: single"
style="font-family: Trebuchet MS"
style="font-size:10.0pt;"
style="color: navy"
```

I can delete a set number of wildcards with a simple . command:

```
:%s/ style="........"//g
```

But is there a way to make the . variable length in that substitute command, so that one command will delete every style attribute in the whole document?

PS - I've searched for frontpage cleaners and found a few, but not clear how reliable they are, so scripting it myself instead.  Open to suggestions here though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should eliminate all the style attributes in your HTML:

```
:%s/ style=".*"//g
```

**Edit**: Sam Brinck brings up a good point. My code was based on your example alone. This code would gobble up too much, say if there were other attributes following the `style="..."` attribute. A safer alternative may be:

```
:%s/ style="[^"]*"//g
```

which means - remove all characters after `style="` that is *NOT a double quote* `[^"]` until the next double quote is encountered. Thanks Sam!

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  Could have sworn I tried that, but apparently not.  Muchos gracias!

Comment: be a little careful with though `.*` is greedy, meaning that if there is more than one `"` on the line it will grab everything to the last `"`.

Comment: Haha, thank you, that could indeed cause some pain.  @Web User, thx for the edit.